# The recycler view item clicks not working if I put recycler view inside swipe refresh layout

Tags: android-recyclerview, crash, swiperefreshlayout, pull-to-refresh

The recycler view item clicks not working if I put recycler view inside swipe refresh layout. adding the layout and constrain layout and recycler view java logic below. In this music player app, when I try to play a song after using this Swipe to refresh layout, app crashes. I am also attachng the logcat error below

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="com.siliconligase.musicplayer.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:menu="@menu/search_btn"
            app:subtitleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/homeControlWrapper"
        android:paddingVertical="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/x_sm"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/homeControlWrapper"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appbar" />


    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeControlWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
```

```java
 private void showSongs(List<Song> songs) {
        if (songs.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No songs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        // save songs
        allSongs.clear();
        allSongs.addAll(songs);

        // update the toolbar title
        String title = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + "  (" + songs.size() + " Songs)";
        SpannableStringBuilder spannableTitle = new SpannableStringBuilder(title);
        spannableTitle.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.6f), title.indexOf("  ") + 1, spannableTitle.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle(spannableTitle);
        // layout manager
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        // songs adapter
        songAdapter = new SongAdapter(this, songs, player, playerView);
        // set the adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerview.setAdapter(songAdapter);

        // Add long press listener to items in RecyclerView
        GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View itemView = recyclerview.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (itemView != null) {
                    int position = recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(itemView);
                    showPopupMenu(itemView, position);
                }
            }

        });

        recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {
                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }

        });
        //swipe refresh layout logic
        //swipe listener
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.primary_color);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
            fetchSongs();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Songs List is Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });


    }
```

> Logcat Error for app crash:Process: com.example.slmusicplayer, PID: 11436
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
> at com.siliconligase.musicplayer.SongAdapter.lambda$onBindViewHolder$0$com-siliconligase-slmusicplayer-SongAdapter(SongAdapter.java:91)
> at com.siliconligase.musicplayer.SongAdapter$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:6)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7156)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7129)
> at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:803)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27543)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7593)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)

The recycler view item clicks not working if I put recycler view inside swipe refresh layout. adding the layout and constrain layout and recycler view java logic below. In this music player app, when I try to play a song after using this *Swipe to refresh layout*, **app crashes.**